# Cannot automatically create classes on ASP.NET MVC & Entity Framework in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am just trying to learn how to create web applications using MVC and i'm following a tutorial to just create a basic application.

I am coming across an issue where I am supposed to build the solution and from that, 2 class files would be automatically created and placed in the Model folder however they are not created upon building the solution. The solution is built successfully with no errors.

I have created an MVC project in VS, created an SQL db, installed Entity framework 6, created a table within the DB and filled it with some data. I have then created a model using the entity data model wizard and used the database as a connection and from that I have built the solution. In the tutorial it states that it should create 2 class files, the table name and a class that inherits the dbcontext class.

When I build the solution, I check the web.config file and the connectionstring property is created. I have noticed that when creating the model, it attempts to install framework 6.2 but instead skips it, I assume this isn't the issue though.

Can anyone just tell me how I can achieve this?

Model folder looks like this;
[image]

It should however look like this;
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are choosing the wrong option in the EF code generator.

1. Right click on the project
2. Select Add -> New Item
3. Choose the option ADO.Net Entity Data Model
   [image]
4. In the next menu in the wizard, choose **"Code First From Database"**. This is where you are going wrong since you are choosing EF Designer from database.
   [image]

Comment: I have already got this to work before using EF Designer from database as that it how the tutorial is stating I should do but now I cannot recreate the scenario where it happened. I was told to only use the EF Designer from database wizard. Would prefer to try and go down using database first